# Topology defined via inclusions - Interior, closure, continuity

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, continuity

> Let $\tau$ be the finest topology where the inclusions $i_k:(C_k,\tau_e)\to \mathbb{R^2}, k=1,2$ and $i_3:(\mathbb{R}^2-(C_1\cup C_2),\tau_e)\to \mathbb{R}^2$ are continuous ($C_1,C_2$ are the circumferences centered in the origin and radius respectively $1$ and $2$).
>
> - Find closure and interior of
>   $$W:=\{ (x,y)\in [0,1]\times \mathbb{R}:1<x^2+y^2\leq 2\} \cup \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}: x^2+y^2=1 \}$$
> - For which $a \in \mathbb{N}$ the function below is continuous
>   $$f_a:(x,y)\in (\mathbb{R}^2,\tau)\to (ax,ay) \in (\mathbb{R}^2,\tau) $$

I'm thinking on this problem for quite a while and since every time I miss some details, I would like to share my thoughts.

---

For the first part I consider
$$A= \{(x,y)\in (0,1)\times \mathbb{R}:1<x^2+y^2< 2\}$$
In euclidean topology each $p=(x,y) \in A$ has an open ball centered in $p$ contained in $A$, call that $B_\epsilon(p)$ so  $i^{-1}_3(B_\epsilon(p))$ is open, so $A$ is a neighborhood of each $p=(x,y) \in A$, indeed open. Since $C_1=i^{-1}_1(\mathbb{R}^2)$, $C_1$ is open in $\tau$ and $B=A\cup C_1$ is open. This lead me to think that
$$W^{\mathrm{o}} = \{ (x,y)\in (0,1)\times \mathbb{R}:1<x^2+y^2< 2\} \cup \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}: x^2+y^2=1 \}$$
I think is the best we can do for the interior if I'm not missing something. For the closure I started thinking about the points on the boundary of $W$ and I think that
$$\overline{W} =\{ (x,y)\in [0,1]\times \mathbb{R}:1\leq x^2+y^2\leq 2\} \cup C_1 $$
In the second part for $a=0$ we have a constant function that is continuous, $a=1$ is the identity function so it's continuous. Let $a>1$ and consider the inverse of $f_a$,  $g_a(x,y)=(\frac{1}{a}x,\frac{1}{a}y)$. Let for example be $a=2$ so $g_2$ map $C_1$ in the circumference of radius $1/2$ centered in the origin, which is not open. I conclude that $f_a$ can not be continuous for $a>1$.

---

I would like to know if this could be a possible solution, if I'm missing something or if I could rephrase better my solution. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: For starters, shouldn't you consider $A$ with $1 < x^2 + y^2 \le 4$, rather than $2$?

Comment: @User actually I made a mistake defining $A$, I edit that. Btw why do you think I should consider your definition of $A$?

Comment: Because the equation for $C_2$ is $x^2 + y^2 = 2^2$.

Comment: @LeeMosher ok but I need to find the interior of $W$ so I think that the part $\{2<x^2+y^2\leq 4\}$ is not that interesting, am I wrong?